# Javascript function to open a file not getting called

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-ajax

i am having problem in calling javascript function
I want to open a file on click of a link.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var refViewer = null;

function OpenViewerWindow(image) {
    return window.open(image, "Viewer", "height=400px,width=550px,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes ,resizable=yes,top=100px,left=234px");

}


function openViewer(image) {

    if (refViewer != null) {
        if (refViewer.closed == false) {
            refViewer.close();
            refViewer = OpenViewerWindow(image);
        }
        else refViewer = OpenViewerWindow(image);
    }
    else
        refViewer = OpenViewerWindow(image);
}   


</script>

<a onclick=javascript:openViewer(@ViewBag.path)><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
```

and the in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult ActivityPosting(int HobbyDetailID)
    {
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/" + HobbyDetailID + "/ReferenceMaterial/" + item.FilePath);
 ViewBag.path = filepath;
    return view();
   }
```

The problem is the javascript function does not get called.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead in your JavaScript `OpenViewerWindow` function (you need to use the `file://` protocol:

```
return window.open("file://" + image, "Viewer", "height=400px,width=550px,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes   ,resizable=yes,top=100px,left=234px")
```

Comment: the problem is openViewer() function itself is not getting called

Comment: Try changing your `a` tag to be this: `<a onclick="openViewer('@ViewBag.path');"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>`

Comment: Can you tell us your **exact** filepath in the @ViewBag.path variable that the window is trying to open?  That must be wrong.

Comment: ya the file path is:E:\HOBBYHOMES(E-PORTFOLIO)\ePortfolio\e-Portfolio\PortFolioContent\1\ReferenceMaterial\prtf_1.docx

Comment: Ah try my edit, it must start with `file:///` not `file://` what I put originally :)

Comment: Actually no it doesn't ignore that, Have you tried hard-coding the path to make sure it works? I think the \ need to be /, Try hard coding `file://E:/HOBBYHOMES(E-PORTFOLIO)/ePortfolio/e-Portfolio/PortFolioContent/1/Referenc‌​eMaterial/prtf_1.docx`

Comment: i hardcoded the entire path.if inside the application i do Ctrl+Click it goes to the file path but when i run it again the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass a string:

```
<a onclick=javascript:openViewer('@ViewBag.path')><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
```

Notice the single quotes. Or even better use Json.Encode to ensure proper encoding of the value that is passed to your `openViewer` javascript function:

```
<a onclick="javascript:openViewer(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.path)))"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
```

Also there's another issue with your code. You use `Server.MapPath` to calculate the url but this method returns the absolute path to the file on the server. The client obviously cannot access it with an absolute path. You should pass an url using the `Url.Content` helper:

```
public ActionResult ActivityPosting(int HobbyDetailID)
{
    string filepath = Url.Content("~/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/" + HobbyDetailID + "/ReferenceMaterial/" + item.FilePath");
    ViewBag.path = filepath;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Oops, that's because I forgot to set `ViewBag.path = filepath;` in my example. I have updated.

Comment: the function is getting called but the file is not opening

Comment: That's another problem with the url that you are requesting. Maybe there's some issue with it.